# Is there a way to statically analyse memory allocation in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, static-analysis

If a piece of memory is dynamically allocated in a function, either it must be freed in the function or a pointer to the piece of memory has to get out of the funcion. So I think it should be possible to track pointers to allocated pieces of memory in a function during static analysis and, if a pointer doesn't get out of the function and its memory isn't freed, the analyser should throw an error.

In C, it's not known which functions output pointers to allocated memory. So for this analysis to work, it should analyse all functions called in the function too.

Sometimes it wouldn't be easy to track the pointer, for example if a pointer to a piece of allocated memory was put to an array and the array was shuffled in a way that's hard to compute. Then the analyser could throw a warning if it can't track the pointer. But the analysis would be helpful for checking if the function has a place where it ends without clean-up (closing files and freeing temporary arrays).

The analysis would be easier if function declarations included information about the ways the function could output a pointer to a piece of allocated memory, similarly to how Java method decalarations include information about which exceptions they throw. That's not in C, but is there a language which has function declarations which include information about how the function can output pointers to pieces of allocated memory? The function declarations could look like this:

```
void* malloc(size_t size) allocates return;

// this function creates an array of unknown size and writes it to *dest,
// returns the size of the array
size_t createArray(int** dest) allocates *dest;
```

Comment: It may not be possible for static analysis, but for dynamic analysis you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: Pointers can be casted into other types, stored in a `static` variable, added, subtracted, etc. So I think that static analysis will be extremely difficult

Comment: If a function allocated several blocks of memory and linked them into an abstract data structure such as a tree or a linked list, you'd need some way to annotate that. Could get messy.

Comment: *That's not in C, but is there a language which has function declarations which include information about how the function can output pointers to pieces of allocated memory?* Not exactly this, but there are languages that guarantee memory safety. Take a look at Rust, for example.

Comment: This seems like something that a powerful IDE might try to do. I checked the CLion documentation, and it doesn't have it.

Comment: A compiler could do some analysis, but a complete solution is impossible because it is equivalent to the Halting Problem. If you had a routine that could always tell whether a routine did allocate memory and fail to free or return it, I could include it in a routine that asked whether it itself did so, and, if the answer were no, allocated memory and returned without freeing or returning the memory, but, if the answer were yes, returned without allocating memory. So the answer would be wrong. Therefore, such a routine cannot exist.